# Keycloak. How to use multiple instances?

Tags: java, vue.js, jakarta-ee, keycloak

My application has 2 Vue frontends and Java backend (and external service). First front for public access (has own keycloak), second for internal (has own keycloak too).
Internal is used for authorization inside another service.

But if i use first frontend, i cant auth in second and vice versa...

I think, cause keycloak context is only one in app...

So, how to use multiple keycloak context in one app?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Please share your code. Otherwise, no one can help you.

Comment: can you specify which code is needed?
too many files, it would be nice to know what is required